# How to use an older version of GLIBC in python (anaconda)?

Tags: python, pyspark, glibc

I'm running a python script which submits a pyspark job on a cluster. However, the job fails with GLIBC issues.

```
Log Contents:
dev-env/bin/python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by dev-env/bin/python)
dev-env/bin/python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by dev-env/bin/python)
```

The problem, I think, is that the GLIBC version on my machine is 2.17. GLIBC version on pyspark cluster is 2.10. I obtained this by opening python and running the command

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.libc_ver()
('glibc', '2.17') # This is my machine
```

One way to resolve this problem IMO is to make sure python on my machine uses GLIBC 2.10. However, I don't know how to do it. I'm using anaconda to create python virtual env. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use an older version of GLIBC in python (anaconda)?

Your problem is *not* that your `pyspark` is using GLIBC-2.17 on your machine. Your problem is that your `pyspark` was *built* against GLIBC-2.17 (or later).

You need to download a different version of `pyspark`, one appropriate for running on GLIBC-2.10 machines. Such version will run fine on GLIBC-2.10 *and all later versions*.